# Ask for a more concise phrase than "fundamental physical and chemical properties"

Tags: phrase-requests, academic-writing

Is there a more concise phrase to say "fundamental physical and chemical properties"?

Comment: You could try *fundamental material properties*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are often referred to as the *intrinsic* properties.

> intrinsic =
>
> basic to a thing, being an important part of making it what it is:
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/intrinsic)

I give you the example of the metal iron: *mass*, *volume* and *density*. *Mass* and *volume* depend on the details of an iron object (an iron ship, an iron nail, an iron filing) and are not intrinsic to the metal iron. The *density* of the iron is intrinsic (about 8 gm/cubic centimetre).

There is an extended, useful and clear presentation of these issues in

> [docs.google](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1XnaSr3yXd9Ibix-sZlazLKi3lzMKSntj35MSv_jXI6o/htmlpresent)